# getting push notification userInfo and presenting ViewControllers through it swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have an application where I used push notification and the notification gets delivered. The problem I am having now is I need to present different ViewControllers depending on the type of notification deliverd which could either be of type

```
      `{
           "body" : "A new property has just been approved under your agency",
           "title" : "New property Approved",
           "type" : "new_property",
           "meta"  : {"property_id" : 4}
       }`
```

or

```
    `{
          "body" : "Chux rated you ",
          "title" : "New Rating",
          "type" : "new_rating",
          "meta"  : {"id" : 4, "user_id" : 7, "role_id" : 2}
      }`
```

so to do this, I realize we have to drill down to the meta and grab what needed which I am still unable to do because whenever I try to get the `meta`, it does return `nil`. below is how it is being done.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("FirebaseTest Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("FirebaseTest Failed to register: \(error)")
    }

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
        log("FirebaseTest 444 \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Print full message.
        log("FirebaseTest  \(userInfo)")
        if application.applicationState == .active {
            log("FirebaseTest App already open")
        } else {
            log("FirebaseTest App opened from Notification")
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        extractUserInfo(userInfo: userInfo)
    }

    func extractUserInfo(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        log("FirebaseTest App already open blllll \(userInfo)", .fuck)

        let type = userInfo["type"] as? String
        print("FirebaseTest App already open type \(type)")
        let meta = userInfo["meta"] as? [String: Any]
        print("FirebaseTest App already open meta \(meta)")

    }

}
```

I have added the userInfo

```
[AnyHashable("meta"): {"property_id":"4"}, AnyHashable("title"): adie, AnyHashable("type"): new_property, AnyHashable("body"): This, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): new_property, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1566819575057749, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = This;
        title = adie;
    };
    }, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.meta"): {"property_id":"4"}]
```

How can I get this meta data and present different controllers depending on the notification type

Comment: *but it does returns `nil`*. **Where**?

Comment: here @vadian print("FirebaseTest App already open meta \(meta)")

Comment: I updated the question I have added the userInfo